# A curious equality of integrals involving the prime counting function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, prime-numbers

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128276/how-many-primes-does-this-sequence-find) discusses the integral, 
$$I(k)=\int_0^k\pi(x)\pi(k-x)dx$$

where $\pi(x)$ is the [prime-counting function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html). For example,
$$I(13)=\int_0^{13}\pi(x)\pi(13-x)dx = 73$$

Using WolframAlpha, the [first 50 values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BIntegrate%5BPrimePi%5Bn-%20x%5D%20PrimePi%5Bx%5D,%20%7Bx,%200,%20n%7D%5D,%7Bn,1,20%7D%5D) for $k=1,2,3,\dots$ are,

$$I(k) = 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 8, 14, 22, 32, 45, 58, 73, 90, 110, 132, 158, 184, 214, 246, 282, 320, 363, 406, 455, 506, 562, 618, 678, 738, 804, 872, 944, 1018, 1099, 1180, 1269, 1358, 1450, 1544, 1644, 1744, 1852, 1962, 2078, 2196, 2321, 2446, 2581, 2718,\dots$$

While trying to find if the above sequence obeyed a pattern, I noticed a rather unexpected relationship:

---

> **Q:** For all $n>0$, is it true,
>   $$I(6n+4) - 2\,I(6n+5) + I(6n+6) \overset{\color{red}?}= 0$$

Example, for $n=1,2$, then 
$$I(10)-2I(11)+I(12)=32-2*45+58 = 0$$
$$I(16)-2I(17)+I(18)=132-2*158+184= 0$$
and so on.

Comment: Note your proposed equation doesn't hold for $n = 0$ as $I(4) = 0$, $I(5) = 1$ and $I(6) = 4$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: A typo. I meant all $n>0$. I will correct it.

Comment: I have checked to confirm what you're asking is true for $n$ up to $18$. However, I have my doubts it'll always work, partially because it doesn't work for $n = 0$. Also, a similar type condition is that $I(6n) - 2I(6n + 1) + I(6n + 2) = 2$, which holds for $1 \le n \le 5$, but at $n = 6$, the LHS becomes $0$ instead. If I get a chance, I will investigate your equation to see if I can figure out why it's true for at least the first $18$ values and, more importantly, will it always stay true. Regardless, though, it's an excellent observation you've made, even if it doesn't always hold.

Comment: I checked your result up to $n=533$ (for $n \geq 534$, I have problems. Would you be interested by a huge table of $I(k)$ (I was able to generate it up to $k=540$). This is  a very interesting problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks for checking, Claude! However, that table would be too huge for MSE. :)

Comment: @JohnOmielan: The conjecture is correct per Greg Martin's answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Oh, can you check your table how many $I(k)$ are prime? I've found 7 so far. That can be a partial answer to Ultradark's question in [the linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128276/how-many-primes-does-this-sequence-find).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I realized later as I was walking outside that your conjecture was correct, basically for the reason given in Greg Martin's answer. I was planning to write it up as an answer, but Greg beat me to it.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Pls send me the data as a txt file. I can copy-paste it into my very old Mathematica. My email is on my profile page.

Comment: Up to $k=540$, $I(k)$ is a prime for this list $$\{13,57,119,167,171,173,175,341,395,397,427,431,473,515,519\}$$

Comment: As I did promise GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 , I delete my "answer" which was the the table of the $I(k)$'s. You can still recover them from the deleted answer (you have a more than sufficient reputation for doing it). What about the suggested idea to submit the sequence to $OEIS$ ? IN any manner, I would like a discussion on chat. When you are availble, open a chat room and tell me to join you there.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Feel free to submit the sequence to OEIS (with a link to this post). You found more of the sequence than I did. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. By the end, did you get my e-mails and the files ? May I suggest that you submit the sequence (with me if you want). But I have had a lot of trouble trying to add stuff in OEIS so I prefer not to do the work. By the way, if you are available, could we go to a chat room ? If yes, open it and tell me. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yes, I got all your emails starting with the 2nd and responded to most. So I assume you didn't get my replies? I also had problems adding stuff in OEIS so I'm deferring that for now.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. I just received **1** e-mail from you where you gave me the MMA syntax.

Comment: Please raise a flag once you don't need the comments anymore. I don't want to complicate your communication, but certainly there is no point to keeping it indefinitely around.

Comment: By the way, this is [A333700](https://oeis.org/A333700) in the OEIS.

Comment: @JianingSong Thanks for the info. Too bad there is no link to this post.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Don't worry, I had already made an edit to that sequence to add the link to this question (and also your observation), before citing this A-number here. :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The answer is yes. Sketch of solution:
$$
I(k) = \int_0^k \sum_{p\le x} \sum_{q\le k-x} 1 \,dx = \sum_p \sum_{q\le k-p} \int_p^{k-q} dx = \sum_p \sum_{q\le k-p} (k-(p+q)) = \sum_{m\le k} r(m)(k-m),
$$
where $r(m)$ is the number of ways of writing $m$ as the sum of two primes. Then
\begin{align}
I(6n+6) &{}-2I(6n+5)+I(6n+4) \\
&= \sum_{m \le 6n+4} r(m)\big((6n+6-m)-2(6n+5-m) +(6m+4-m)\big) + r(6n+5) \\&= 0 + r(6n+5);
\end{align}
and $r(6n+5)=0$ for every $n\ge1$, since the only way the odd integer $6n+5$ can be the sum of two primes is $6n+5=2+(6n+3)$, but $6n+3=3(2n+1)$ is always composite when $n\ge1$.

The same argument gives $I(6n+2)-2I(6n+1)+I(6n) = r(6n+1)$, which is $2$ if $6n-1$ is prime and $0$ otherwise; this is why (as observed by John Omielan) it equals $2$ for $1\le n\le 5$ but $0$ for $n=6$.

Comment: MSE never ceases to amaze me how fast some people can figure out the answer.

Comment: Greg, do you know how to address Ultradark's [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3128276/how-many-primes-does-this-sequence-find) regarding when $I(k)$ is prime?

Comment: This really surprises me since I thought the equation will be eventually false...

Comment: @stressedout it's arguably worse due to the HNQ list